# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. Read/Process Large Excel File(150MB) With Limited Memory (-Xmx130m) using Sax Parser

Tags: java, excel, kotlin, apache-poi, out-of-memory

I want to read big excel file and go though sheets and process rows. But I want to use limited memory so even if excel file is so big than my project memory capacity I want to be able to read and process it. (First of all, Is it even possible?)

After some research, I see that reading excel file **streamly** could be a solution for me so in my kotlin controller I get file in type of StreamingFileUpload according to the [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-docs-mn3/3.1.4/guide/#uploads) for file uploads (6.21 File Uploads).

Then I am creating a temporary file and transfer the file I get as param to temporary file. Then I am sending this temp file to another method where I am trying to process the temp file. (There is no any error here)

```
    @Post("/read-excel-file")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    fun importExcelFile(@Part file: StreamingFileUpload): Mono<MutableHttpResponse<String>> {
        val tempFile: File = File.createTempFile(file.filename, "temp")

        val uploadPublisher: Publisher<Boolean>? = file.transferTo(tempFile);
        if (uploadPublisher != null) {
            return Mono.from(uploadPublisher)
                .map { success ->
                    if (success) {
                        ExcelReaderHandler().readExcelFile(tempFile); //sax parser logic is implemented here
                        HttpResponse.ok("DONE INSIDE")
                    } else {
                        HttpResponse.badRequest("Failed to upload file")
                    }
                }
        }
        return Mono.just(HttpResponse.ok("DONE"))
    }
```

After reading excel file, I want to process it and as far as I can see the best way for that is Sax Parser way. So I implemented Sax Parser logic according to the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) of poi.apache official page in my readExcelFile method.

But the problem is with **OPCPackage.open(file)** method which is required to use in sax parser logic. The method just can not handle the temp file I give and throws memory error.

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun readExcelFile(file: File) {
    try {
        val factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance()
        val saxParser: SAXParser = factory.newSAXParser()
        val opcPackage: OPCPackage = OPCPackage.open(file)
        val here = "here" // can not reach here
```

I thought it might be about outdated version thing of poi library but I am using 5.2.3 version of poi (latest is 5.2.5)

Comment: Does opening the file [as readonly](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html#open-java.io.File-org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageAccess-) help?

Comment: Please do not use images for text information in Stackoverflow. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: @Gagravarr thanks for your reply but it didn't help, same error pops up.

Comment: The snippet seems to be Kotlin. Why don't you add the Kotlin tag?

Comment: @aled You are right! I have added it now.

Comment: In 2024, 130m Xmx is nothing - why are you not at least trying more memory? 130m will barely load the classes - let alone leave anything for parsing the xlsx file.

Comment: @PJFanning My project even works with 60m Xmx so there is no problem with 130m. I know more memory like 200m will work for me if I upload 150 mb excel file but I am trying to read data streamly not read it once. Reading all data would not be good for server, if uploaded data file is soo big.

Comment: https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader?tab=readme-ov-file#reading-very-large-excel-files includes 2 POI settings that reduce the memory overhead of OPCPackage.open(file)

Comment: @PJFanning thank you for your reply, I am gonna look for it.